# I received an email from UKVI stating; We have made an error concerning your visa. Please submit your passport to the VAC

Tags: visas, uk

I received a visa and after a few days got this message:

> We have made an error concerning your visa.
>
> Please submit your passport to the Visa Application Centre (VAC) where you originally made your visa application in order to receive your vignette with the correct endorsement.
>
> Please take a copy of this email to the VAC when you submit your passport.
>
> If the passport is already with the Visa Application Centre, please ignore this email.
>
> Apologies for any inconvenience this may have caused you.

My passport was submitted 4 days ago, and until now there has been no acknowledgement or mail, and my travel is in less than a week. Any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. I doubt there's any useful advice we can offer, you'll need to call the VAC and ask about timelines and if necessary take your passport back.

Comment: You mention your passport was submitted 4 days ago, but it’s not clear from your question if your passport is still with the VAC.  If it is, the penultimate paragraph (*…please ignore this email*) applies.